# ObjectBox relations - want to return a list of just the relation box

Tags: objectbox

Looking at the docs for relations at
https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#add-query-conditions-for-related-entities-links , and not using any @Backlink annotation in the Entity itself, I want to get a List of objects from the related table.

In the example in the docs this works with...

```
// get all Address objects with street "Sesame Street"...
val builder = box.query().equal(Address_.street, "Sesame Street")
// ...which are linked from a Person named "Elmo"
builder.backlink(Person_.addresses).equal(Person_.name, "Elmo")
val sesameStreetsWithElmo = builder.build().find()
```

I think this is Kotlin, which is not my forte, but it makes enough sense (apart from what the type of `val sesameStreetsWithElmo` is)

I would assume I get back a list of Address objects, as the first comment says. But in my tests with my own code, I was getting back a List of Person objects. Am I wrong in what I expect to get back? Is it right that I get back a Person object with the name Elmo, but with only Address objects where street is Sesame Street? I want to just have the Address objects, but I was getting return a list of Person.

If this is correct, then I've just misunderstood (maybe update the docs to help, because it seems to me to be pretty clear that this should only return Address objects). But if not, then maybe someone can tell me where I went wrong.

(I'm writing this on my work machine, without access to my personal project where I can give an example of my own code, but I can add that later if it helps)

**UPDATE**: I've tried it again and have provided code.

CODE

From the `build().find()` I would expect to get back `List<DailyChallengeRoundEntity>` as that is what the box is made up from (I'll show that in more code samples later). But instead it says that find() is returning `List<DailyChallengeProgressEntity>`

```
public List<DailyChallengeRoundEntity> getRounds(String uniqueId, String date) {
    QueryBuilder<DailyChallengeRoundEntity> builder = box.query().equal(DailyChallengeRoundEntity_.date, date);
    List<DailyChallengeProgessEntity> dailyChallengeProgessEntities = builder.backlink(DailyChallengeProgessEntity_.rounds).equal(DailyChallengeProgessEntity_.uniqueId, uniqueId).build().find();
}
```

And to show how my box is generated, the box in this class comes from first the constructor...

```
public DailyChallengeRoundManager(DB db) {
    super(db, DailyChallengeRoundEntity.class);
}
```

which calls

```
public BaseDbManager(DB db, Class<T> boxType) {
    box = db.getBox(boxType);
}
```

and the DB class looks like...

```
private void createMyObjectBox() throws IOException {
    File objectstorefile = new File("../objectBox/objectstorefile");
    if(!objectstorefile.isDirectory()) {
        objectstorefile.mkdirs();
    }
    File boxStoreDir = objectstorefile;

    if(store == null) {
        store = MyObjectBox.builder().directory(boxStoreDir).build();
    }
}

public<T> Box<T> getBox(Class<T> object) {
    if(store == null) {
        try {
            createMyObjectBox();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return store.boxFor(object);
}
```

and my two classes (I'm not using @Backlink but the docs say I don't have to. Although I've tried various combos of using Annotations etc and it still hasn't worked)

```
package uk.co.russellwheeler.db.entities;

@io.objectbox.annotation.Entity
public class DailyChallengeRoundEntity extends BaseEntity {

    //fields are duplicated from parent table, but it makes it much easier to search on later
    private String uniqueId;
    private String date;

    private int round;
    private String word;
    private int score;

    public DailyChallengeRoundEntity() {
    }

    public DailyChallengeRoundEntity(String uniqueId, String date, int round, String word, int score) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.date = date;
        this.round = round;
        this.word = word;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getRound() {
        return round;
    }

    public void setRound(int round) {
        this.round = round;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}



package uk.co.russellwheeler.db.entities;

import io.objectbox.relation.ToMany;

@io.objectbox.annotation.Entity
public class DailyChallengeProgessEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private String uniqueId;
    private String date;
    private ToMany<DailyChallengeRoundEntity> rounds;

    public DailyChallengeProgessEntity() {
    }

    public DailyChallengeProgessEntity(String uniqueId, String date) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public ToMany<DailyChallengeRoundEntity> getRounds() {
        return rounds;
    }

    public void setRounds(ToMany<DailyChallengeRoundEntity> rounds) {
        this.rounds = rounds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get back the type of the `Box` you called `query()` on. Your assumption is correct, you will get back a list of `Address` objects in this example.

However, this pointed me to a issue of the ObjectBox docs. The docs should be very clear about the type of the Box being used. Thus, I just updated 'box', used in the two code examples, to either 'personBox' or 'addressBox' to make this clear.

That's what I am guessing happened in your code as well; using a Box of type A to build a query for type B...
(if that's not it, maybe post some code and I'll update this answer.)

Comment: I'm 99% certain I started the query on a box of type B, and was using .backLink() to link it to type A, but I was being given back a List<A>. Unfortunately I've deleted most of that code, but I should be able to go back and find an old commit with it in. I'll try and post some code later...

Comment: Hey @markus-junginger I've added some code to show you how I use it, and how it gives me back the Type A, not the Type B as I expected. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Update: actually the code will throw at runtime if `build()` is called on a `backlink()` sub-query, like you are trying to do. So as said: call `build().find()` on the original query `builder`. Not on the one returned by `backlink()`.
Added Java examples to docs as well. https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#add-query-conditions-for-related-entities-links